# Is an exact operator, unitary equivalent to a banded operator?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.

**Definition** : Let $(e_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis.
  $T \in B(H)$ is **banded** if $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $
(Te_{n}, e_{m})\ne 0 \Rightarrow \vert n-m \vert \leq r$.

**Definition** : A $C^{*}$-algebra is [exact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_C*-algebra)  if it preserves exact sequences under the minimum tensor product.

**Property** : A $C^{*}$-algebra is exact if and only if :

- it's nuclearly embeddable into $B(H)$.
- it's isomorphic to a subalgebra of the [Cuntz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuntz_algebra) algebra $\mathcal{O}_2$.

**Definition** : An operator $T \in B(H)$ is **exact** if it generates an exact $C^{*}$-algebra $C^{*}(T)$.

The following is known by N. Ozawa (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452908/is-every-operator-unitary-equivalent-to-a-banded-operator/453971#453971)) :  if $T \in B(H)$ unitary equivalent to a banded operator, then $T$ is exact. What about the converse ?

> Is an exact operator, unitary equivalent to a banded operator ?

Comment: [Cross-posted on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457084/is-an-exact-operator-unitary-equivalent-to-a-banded-operator)

Comment: I warn the reader that *banded* and *bounded* are two different concepts in operator theory.

Comment: the notion of banded depends on orthonormal basis?

Comment: @YvesCornulier: yes it depends on the choice of the orthonormal basis. For example : let $(e_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis, then the operator $T: e_{n} \to e_{2n}$ is not banded, but by reordering the basis, it becomes banded. So "to be a banded operator" depends on the choice of the orthonormal basis, but "to be unitary equivalent to a banded operator", not.

Comment: The property you state is true for separable $C^*$-algebras. Is that a standing assumption of yours?

Comment: Yes @UlrichPennig, my post is in the framework of *separable* $C^{*}$-algebras.

Comment: What happens for the operator $T$ given by multiplication on the coordinate on $L^2[0,1]$?  Is there an orthonormal basis making this banded?

Comment: @MatthewDaws: I'm not sure to well-understand your operator $T$. Is it the [Volterra operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_operator) ? Do you think that the Volterra operator is exact and not unitary equivalent to a banded operator ?

Comment: No: let $H=L^2[0,1]$ and for $\xi\in L^2[0,1]$ define $T$ to be the multiplication operator $T(\xi)(t) = t\xi(t)$.  Then $C^*(T) \cong C[0,1]$ is commutative...

Comment: @MatthewDaws: ok I see, $T$ is a shift on $(t^{n})_{n}$, but it's **not** an orthonormal basis. The set $\{1, s_{n}=sin(2πnt) , c_{n}=cos(2πnt) \}$ is an orthonormal basis, but $T$ is not banded on it.  The question of whether or not there is an orthonormal basis for which $T$ is banded is perhaps obvious for someone here. Let me think...

Comment: Taking one of the two standard generators of $\mathcal O_2$, is this unitarily equivalent to a banded operator?  I suspect not, and this would show that whether or not an operator $T$ is unitarily equivalent to a banded operator does not just depend on the abstract C*-algebra $C^*(\{T\})$ together with the placement of $T$ in this C*-algebra.  (Since the C*-algebra of the one-sided shift generates the same C*-algebra as one of the Cuntz algebra generators.)

Comment: @MatthewDaws's example is surely the **first** thing that should have been tried...

Comment: Also, surely it is more natural to look not just at banded operators, but at operators which are limits (in norm topology) of banded operators. This would correspond to the Roe algebra of **Z** if I remember correctly